# Apply Kendo UI dropdown styles to a select element

Tags: kendo-ui

My app is on an older version of Kendo UI ~V2014.

I need to create a drowdown list with a tree view which this version of kendo does not support.

I'm trying to determine what kendo css classes to apply to get my select element to look similar to the other drop downs on my site.

```

```
<select class="k-widget k-dropdown-wrap k-header">
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>- Select -</option>
   <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="German Cars">
     <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

```

Comment: I guess it will depend if you are using skins or not. The best way is to inspect the form elements on your browser and check the class name you need to overrride.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I've determined this is not practical to do.

The Kendo drop-down module is built using spans not a select element, therefor the styles and behaviors do not exactly translate.

An alternative is to use two cascading drop-downs.